# Using remote standalone cluster in local Spark application error "scala.Option; local class incompatible"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I set up a remote Spark standalone cluster with several nodes. For that I downloaded this Spark release: spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop1 (because we have an old Hadoop 1 service running)

In my local Scala program I defined the path to the master:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://node01.kdlan:7078").setAppName("My App")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

When starting my local local program I see this error in the log:

```
16/01/15 10:35:34 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node01.kdlan:7078] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]
```

On the the remote master I can see in the Spark log files:

```
16/01/15 10:35:34 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@myip:43288] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [scala.Option; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -114498752079829388, local class serialVersionUID = -2062608324514658839].
16/01/15 10:35:34 INFO Master: myip:43288 got disassociated, removing it.
```

Somewhere I read that the Spark dependencies should be marked as 'provided' which I did in my build.sbt. There are no other library dependencies defined.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.5.1" % "provided"
```

The Spark version matches (1.5.1) and the Scala main version too (2.11), so where does the incompatible Scala Option class come from and how to solve this?

Comment: How did you installed Spark? Because the default Spark installation uses Scala 2.10. If you do want to use Scala 2.11 you have to compile properly Spark with Scala 2.11 and install your compiled version.

Comment: @mark91 I simply downloaded the zip "spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop1.tgz" from the Spark homepage - I didn't compile it myself. Thanks for this hint, this looks promising. I'll tell if I was successfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to [mark91](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2825806/mark91).

The reason why this error occurs is, that the pre-compiled Spark distributions that you can download from the Spark homepage are compiled with Scala 2.10 - thus the version missmatch on scala.Option class.

If you want to use Scala 2.11, then you have to compile it yourself. There is a source-code package on the Spark homepage that you can download for that. There is info [how to compile](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211) it as well.

There is this note on the Spark homepage, however I missed this.

> Note: Scala 2.11 users should download the Spark source package and
>   build with Scala 2.11 support.